# Should I add a element name in front of '#id' or '.class' selector?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm reading [the book: CSS Mastery: Advanced Web Standards Solutions](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430223979), and finding the css code inside is almost writed in this format:

```
elementName#idName   
elementName.className
```

but, I'm used to write code ignoring element name with this format:

```
 #idName   
.className
```

so, I want to figure out what difference is between the two format.

Actually, I understand when should use type.class. And, I just want to find out the impact when I use type.class insead of only using .class when there is only one kind of tag here.

There must be some impact on performance.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a real life scenario as when to use elementName and when to just use class or id name:

HTML:

```
<a class="blue">I'm blue and underline</a>
<span class"blue">I'm blue and bold</a>
```

CSS:

```
.blue {
   color:blue //will make both <a> and <span> blue
}

a.blue {
   text-decoration:underline // will make only the <a> tags underline
}
span.blue {
   font-weight:bold //will make only the <span> tags bold
}
```

but remember when it comes to IDs you should not have duplicate IDs on your page anyway, this is more practical for classes

Answer (score 1):

The difference between the two is that the first:

```
       element.class
```

Is calling the element with that specific class.

And the second:

```
        .class
```

Is calling all elements that contain this class

Comment: I'm sure he understands the difference.  I think he's just asking why you would use a `type.class` selector over the `.class` selector in cases where the type is known.

Comment: Actually, I understand when should use type.class. And, I just want to find out the impact when I use type.class insead of only using .class when there is only one kind of tag here.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the `element` inclusion in the selector is a holdover from days where some browsers required it (I think IE5 does, but I could be wrong).  This is no longer necessary, and it does not make sense to include element selector for at least three reasons:

1. It slows the selector down since the element selector is slower than the other two -- especially `id`.  Assuming selection is optimized so that fast selection is done first (e.g. the element with the matching id is found before the element selector is checked), there is still the additional step of checking the element selector.
2. It's not as extensible since you can't change the element without also having to change the selector.  The implication is also that `div.class` would function differently than `label.class`, but I think that the class should be descriptive enough.
3. It changes the specificity of the selector.  This could be very frustrating for some developers who may want to change `<div class="foo">` from green to red:

```
div.foo { color: green; }
/* below is not applied since the above has higher specificity */
.foo { color: red; }
```

---

I've never heard an argument that supports `type.class` unless old browsers need to be supported.